# C# Installation - Install software on multiple computers simultaneously

Tags: c#, installation, upgrade, installation-package, silent-installer

I have a c# application that will be installed on several different network computers. The software changes on occasion.  I was wondering if there was a way to upgrade or install the new version of software on all the network computers at the same time from the server computer.

I will be triggering the install, so there will not need to be checks for new versions or anything like that.

So, what I need is some method of a mass install when I trigger it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at ClickOnce? Not exactly mass install but the upgrades are automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce supports "broadcasting" updates...

Answer (score 2):

Howzabout a software installation AD Group Policy? This would do exactly what you need, assuming you have an AD domain.